# Load R files from URL

Tags: r, file, url, load

Is there a way to load (not run) R scripts from URLs? `file.edit()` only seems to work for local files. For example the following test file: https://a.uguu.se/wzhzrg_test.R

Comment: `readLines()` perhaps?

Comment: `source(url)` should work fine as long as you can access the url from browser

Comment: source("https://a.uguu.se/wzhzrg_test.R")

Comment: Both of these run the script. What I'm looking for is a way to open the script file in RStudio, rather than running it.

Comment: by "open the script file in RStudio" do you mean in an editable source tab?

Comment: @hrbrmstr That is indeed what you mean. If you know a way to do this, that'd be great. If not, then J_F's solution will suffice.

Comment: roger that. there's your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rs_url_open <- function(URL) {
  tf <- tempfile(fileext=".R")
  download.file(URL, tf, quiet=TRUE)
  rstudioapi::navigateToFile(tf)
}

rs_url_open("https://a.uguu.se/wzhzrg_test.R")
```

Comment: Thank you as well for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`url.show("https://a.uguu.se/wzhzrg_test.R")`

This shows you the code but you do not source the code.

Comment: Not exactly what I mean, since I'm trying to open an editable version in a new tab. But this will do as well. Thanks!